# Decimal expansions of $0.999\cdot\cdot$ and $1.000\cdot \cdot$ (infinite digits)

Tags: limits, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion, irrationality-measure

I am reading a passage from the book Foundation of Mathematics by Ian Stewart, and I need some help to make sure I understand it properly.

A real number can be expresed by the following unique decimal expansion:

$a_0.a_1a_2\cdot \cdot \cdot a_n \le x \lt a_0.a_1a_2\cdot \cdot \cdot a_n + \frac{1}{10^n}$  [formula 1]

Apparently this approach does not allow for the expansion of $0.9999 \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot $ i.e. infinite $9$s.

That is because if we try to express it like that we have ($0.999999..9$ means $n$ $9s$):

$0.999999..9 \le  0.9999 \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot  \lt 0.999999..9 + \frac{1}{10^n} \implies 0 \lt 1 - 0.9999 \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot \le \frac{1}{10^n}$ for all $n \in N$

This last condition is impossible by Archimides' condition: since $1 - 0.9999 \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot \gt 0$ which means that the $2$ numbers are different then it means there must exist $n$ with $\frac{1}{10^n} \lt 1 - 0.9999 \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot$.
But according to the inequality we have $ 1 - 0.9999 \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot \le \frac{1}{10^n}$

Is my explanation so far correct? The book just mentions it is impossible but I want to make sure my understanding of why it is impossible is correct.

Now an alternative way that could allow to express $0.9999 \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot$ would be to change the equality signs i.e.:

$a_0.a_1a_2\cdot \cdot \cdot a_n \lt x \le a_0.a_1a_2\cdot \cdot \cdot a_n + \frac{1}{10^n}$   [formula 2]

This would lead to:

$0 \le 1 - 0.9999 \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot \lt \frac{1}{10^n}$

Now since $0 \le 1 - 0.9999 \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot$ we have $2$ cases:

Case $1$: $0 \lt 1 - 0.9999\cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot$ which is the same case mentioned earlier which leads to impossibility
Case $2$: $0 = 1 - 0.9999\cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot$ which means that $1$ and $0.999\cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot$ are the same number.
Hence we are able to express $0.999\cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot$ as a decimal expression of $1$.

Is my understanding so far correct?

Then the text follows saying that the [formula 2] does not allow the expansion of $1.000\cdot\cdot\cdot$ i.e. infinite $0$s

This part I am not sure I get it either.
I suppose the equation becomes (with $n$ digits at left and right side of the inequality) :

$1.0000 \lt 1.000\cdot \cdot \cdot \le 1.0001$
and by doing the same manipulation as earlier we end up with:
$0 \le 1.0001 - 1.000\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot\cdot\lt \frac{1}{10^n}$

and by applying the same use case we get that $1.0001$ with the $n$ digits is the same expression as $1.000\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot$

But somehow I don't think I understand the idea properly.
Could someone please help me?

**Update:**
I realized that this is has to be wrong:
$1.0000 \lt 1.000\cdot \cdot \cdot \le 1.0001$

Because $1.000\cdot \cdot \cdot$ is actually $1$ hence we can't have $1.0000 \lt 1.000\cdot \cdot \cdot$ and so the formula 2 is invalid.
But formula 1 should hold because $1.0000 \le 1.000\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot$

Comment: The reasoning given doesn't seem to be very well-expressed to me but the idea is right: if the expansion for $x$ ends in a infinite sequence of $9$s say $a_i = 9$ for $i \ge n$ for some $n$ then $x = a_0.a_1 \cdots a_n +1/10^n$, so you don't have $x < a_0.a_1 \cdots a_n +1/10^n$ for all $n$. Similarly, if the $a_i$ are all $0$ for $i \ge n$ for some $n$, then you don't have $ a_0.a_1 \cdots a_n < x$.

Comment: @RobArthan: if $x$ ends in a infinite sequence of $9s$? But the digits before $a_i$ are also $9$. How is it that $x = a_0.a1 \cdot \cdot \cdot  + \frac{1}{10}$ I didn't understand

Comment: I was looking at the general case: what we want (in the first part) is to outlaw representations that end in an infinite number of $9$s. Representing $x = 1$ as $0.999\cdots$ is just the simplest example of what we are trying to ban. And our ban succeeds: taking $n = 1$, we find $x \not< 0.9 + 1/10 =x$, so we don't allow that representation.

Comment: @RobArthan: Taking $n = 1$ (with $a_0 = 0$) we have that $0.9 \le x \lt 0.9 + \frac{1}{10} \Leftrightarrow 0.9 \le x \lt 1$. So I can't understand what you mean. Additionally you say "trying to ban" but the text mentions it as a side-effect

Comment: @Jim What Rob says is that we have uniqueness, if we rule out the period $\bar 9$. So the issue with this period leading to distinct representations for the same number is harmless and can easily be removed.

Comment: @Peter: What do you mean by uniqueness? What would be the difference with a repeating e.g. $7$?

Comment: @Jim Without period $\bar 9$ , it cannot happen that there are two different decimal expansions for the same real number.

Comment: @Peter: What are the two decimal expansions for $.999...$? The formula $a_0.a_1a_2\cdot \cdot \cdot a_n \le x \lt a_0.a_1a_2\cdot \cdot \cdot a_n + \frac{1}{10^n}$  according to the text can not even produce that number

Comment: @Peter: I updated the post

Comment: @RobArthan: I updated the post

Comment: @RobArthan: In your first comment, you say that "if the expansion of $x$ ends in an infinite sequence of $9$s" which I think means $x = 0.999\cdot \cdot \cdot $ but then in the end of the sentence you say "then $x=a_0.a_1\cdot \cdot \cdot a_n + 1/10^n$. How is $x$ now defined differently?

Comment: An expansion like $0.123999\cdots$ also ends in an infinite sequence of $9$s. An expansion that ends in an infinite sequence of $9$s is equivalent to one that ends in an infinite sequence of $0$: e.g., $0.999\cdots = 1.000\cdots$, $47.5329999\cdots = 47.533000\cdots$.

Comment: @RobArthan: Does this make sense? $1.000 \le 1.0000\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot  \lt 1.0001$ where the left and right bound have $n$ digits?