# Correct comparison of real number for n digits precision (absolute vs relative difference)

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, decimal-expansion, floating-point, number-comparison

To compare if $2$ real numbers are equal, we define a desirable precision e.g. $n$ digits and then check if the following condition holds: $-\frac{1}{10^n} \lt x - y \lt \frac{1}{10^n}$
Now I was reading a piece of code that does the following (I will translate it in pseudo code, the original is in Java):

```
function compare (x, y)  {  
  epsilon = 0.000001  

  diff = (x - y) / max(|x|, |y|)   

  if(diff < -epsilon) // comment that this means x is smaller smaller  
  else if(diff > epsilon) // comment that this x is larger
  else // comment that they are equal    
}
```

So it is the application of the aforementioned condition (where epsilon is $\frac{1}{10^6}$ i.e. precision up to $6$ digits).

But I don't understand this line:

```
  diff = (x - y) / max(|x|, |y|),
```

Is there any benefit to divide the $(x - y)$ by the max absolute value of the $2$ before doing the comparison instead of just doing the direct comparison?
It seems some kind of normalization but I don't understand what is the benefit

**Update**
After the comments I can see that there is an absolute/relative difference approach when comparing real numbers.
It seems to me that relative difference is always correct/better than absolute. Is there a case when it is better to use absolute difference?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130866/discussion-on-question-by-jim-comparing-real-numbers-to-a-certain-precision-and).

Comment: The comments are very helpful, I was wondering in cases like this how come there is no answer posted. Does my post need improvements?

Comment: Where is this piece of code from?

Comment: If your original problem is solved, it may be better to post an answer and ask the updated new question in another post.

Comment: @user: I am not really sure if what I have understood as a conclusion is the answer. I.e. *always* use relative comparison for reals. What if I updated the post? Is there a way to improve it?

Comment: This seems more a programming problem, perhaps numerical analysis. Again, where is the code from?

Comment: @user: I don't have an online reference link to it. It is part of an algorithm for calculating a square root of a number. It is not a programming problem because my question is strictly related to the correct comparison of real numbers

Comment: I am not saying your post is not a mathematical question. But floating-point numbers are not real numbers, and your questions are really about comparing two floating-point numbers, not two "real numbers".

Comment: I  am confused with your "update" of the post. Your original question asks the advantage of using the relative difference; now you change your question to ask when the absolute difference is good and you don't need an answer to the original one any more?

Comment: This may be useful for you: http://c-faq.com/fp/fpequal.html

Comment: @user:Floating point is a representation of real numbers. The math book I was reading in regards to treating two real numbers as different, mentions using the absolute difference. In that piece of code which uses floats, considering as just an application of the math on real numbers, I was confused about the relative difference approach. The update was because from the comments I concluded that we should always use the relative approach but I am not 100% sure. So I tried to update the question to include that information. Perhaps I made it more confusing.

Comment: @user: the link you shared is very useful. Is there a more analytical/math resource covering this topic?

Comment: Floating point numbers, as a representation of real numbers *in the machine*, [are not real numbers](https://indico.cern.ch/event/814979/contributions/3401175/attachments/1831476/3107964/FloatingPointArithmetic.pdf). "considering as just an application of the math on real numbers" NO. They are not the same thing. The set of floating point numbers, for instance, do not obey the axioms of real numbers. One reason you have the difference between the relative/absolute approaches is that they are NOT the same.

Comment: That is the "math book" you are reading? Which book is the code from?

Comment: @user: The math book is Ian's Stewart Foundation of mathematics. I original thought that in math we would be interested in a definition of comparing 2 numbers based on the number of decimal places, but now I realize that this is not useful in math as in programming. Basically I guess the point of the passage was that a mathematician can always distinguish between $2$ numbers by taking enough decimal digits and there is no need for relative vs absolute difference distinction. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two usual ways of comparing numbers.  We either compute the relative error or the absolute error.  The absolute error between $x$ and $y$ is $|x-y|$.  The relative error is this quantity divided by $x,y,$ or something like that.  Your routine uses $\max (|x|,|y|)$, which is a very reasonable choice.  If $x$ and $y$ are close, it doesn't matter much what you choose.

The advantage of absolute error is that it plays well with addition.  If I add up four numbers that each have a maximum absolute error of $\frac 18$ the sum has a maximum error of $\frac 12$.  You can think of trying to pack four boxes across the trunk of your car.  If you wonder whether they will fit, measure each one with a certain absolute error.  You know the error of the sum is no more than four times that.

Relative error is what you get when you say something is accurate to one part in a hundred, thousand, or million.  Relative error has two advantages.  One is that it plays well with multiplication and division.  If you multiply four numbers that are each good to one part in a thousand, the product is good (almost) to four parts in a thousand.  The almost comes from second order terms that are small if the individual measurements are rather accurate.  The other advantage is that it doesn't care about the scale of the numbers.  If I measure a length as 1000.0mm, the maximum absolute error is $0.05mm$.  If I measure in meters, it becomes $1.0000m$ and the maximum absolute error is $0.00005m$.  It seems strange that changing the unit of measure, when I have no idea what a reasonable size is, should change the error.  Both of these have a relative error of $5\cdot 10^{-5}$, which seems more reasonable.  If you blindly ask for absolute error of no more than $10^{-6}$, which seems pretty good, you would accept $10^{-6}$ as a square root of $10^{-100}$ because it is within $10^{-6}$ of the true answer $10^{-50}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Super clear and helpful! 1) When you say: "The relative error is this quantity divided by $x,y,$ or something like that" what do you mean by "or something like that"? I understand that you consider taking the max(|x|,|y|) as one valid approach. But what other approaches are there? 2) If I say that as a conclusion one should just forget doing any kind of absolute comparisons completely, and just do relative ones, would that be correct?  Because it seems that absolute comparison works good for specific cases, but relative comparison works for all cases,right?

Comment: No, absolute comparison is useful.  My example of boxes in a car shows one case.  If one box is twice the size of another you want the absolute error to be controlled so you know the error bound on the sum.  The "or something like that" means it doesn't really matter whether you divide by $x,y,$ or the maximum.  When the error is small the differences are small enough not to change the result significantly.

Comment: In the example with the cars, when you say: "measure each one with a certain absolute error" what is the reference we use to determine there is an error? We don't measure between the boxes right?

Comment: Also if you have time and is possible I had asked also the following about real numbers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286269/decimal-expansions-of-0-999-cdot-cdot-and-1-000-cdot-cdot-infinite-digits if you could have a look at it I would be super grateful

Comment: I guess you mean absolute error comparing to actual size or accuracy of measurement. Sorry for the trivial question. I try to be careful to avoid any wrong understanding